# Проблема с text-shadow

Tags: html, css, svg

Нужно сделать вот такой текст:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

CSS Hat выдает следующий код по нему:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Когда применяю эти стили получаем совершенно другой рисунок. Предпологаю что `CSS Hat` не выдает какие-то градиенты. Помогите разобраться, как сделать такой же текст.

**Upd** 
Текст должен быть прозрачным и одновременно от контура букв распространялась тень.

```css
p {
 font-size: 128px;
 font-weight: 700;
 text-shadow: 0 0 85px #131824;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<p>details</p>
```

Comment: Вероятно CSS Hat выдал лишь то что смог разобрать, а не то что Вы нарисовали.

Comment: Видимо так и есть

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Вариант с применением `svg filter`

В вопросе автору нужен был и прозрачный текст и одновременно тень от текста на background.  Может и есть вариант решения с `mask`, чтобы сделать прозрачные буквы, но  одновременное выполнение  двух условий: прозрачности и тени в этом варианте не получилось.

Решение состоит из суммы нескольких простых приемов:

- Прозрачность текста достигается - `fill="none" stroke="white"`
- Применение двух команд  c одинаковым текстом друг над другом
- К нижней строчке текста применяется фильтр размытия Гаусса
  Используя все эти составляющие и комбинируя изменения атрибутов внутри них можно получить интересные эффекты:

*Прозрачность букв и внешняя тень, как у автора вопроса:*

```css
#txt1 {
   font: 900 500% 'Arial Black', sans-serif;
  font-size:160px;
   filter:url(#gauss);
} 
#txt2 {
   font: 900 500% 'Arial Black', sans-serif;
  font-size:160px;
}
```

```html
 <div  class="container">
<svg   width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 800 800" >

    <defs>
  <mask id="txt1" width="1000px" height="1000px">
   <rect width="100%" height="100%" filter="url(#gauss)"/>
   <text x="-100" y="200px"  style="fill:white;stroke-width:1;stroke:white;text-transform: uppercase;">details</text>
    </mask> 
 <filter id="gauss"
    x="-20%" y="-20%" width="1000" height="1000">
       <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="15"/> 
      <feOffset dx="10" dy="10" result="offsetblur"/> 
   </filter>
   </defs>
  
 <image x="-200" y="-410" width="1000px" height="1000px"
 xlink:href="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/hawaii-beach.jpg"  >
 </image>  
 <text id="txt1" x="10" y="240px"  style="fill:none;stroke-width:12;stroke:white;text-transform: uppercase; ">details</text> 
 <text id="txt2" x="10" y="245px"  style="fill:none;stroke-width:5;stroke:white;text-transform: uppercase; ">details</text>
</svg>
 </div>
```

**Прозрачность букв с внутренней тенью:**

```css
#txt1 {
   font: 900 500% 'Arial Black', sans-serif;
  font-size:160px;
   filter:url(#gauss);
} 
#txt2 {
   font: 900 500% 'Arial Black', sans-serif;
  font-size:160px;
 
 
}
```

```html
 <div  class="container">
<svg   width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 800 800" >

    <defs>
  <mask id="txt1" width="1000px" height="1000px">
   <rect width="100%" height="100%" filter="url(#gauss)"/>
   <text x="-100" y="200px"  style="fill:white;stroke-width:1;stroke:white;text-transform: uppercase;">details</text>
    </mask> 
 <filter id="gauss"
    x="-20%" y="-20%" width="1000" height="1000">
       <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="5"/> 
      <feOffset dx="2" dy="5" result="offsetblur"/> 
   </filter>
   </defs>
  
 <image x="-200" y="-410" width="1000px" height="1000px"
 xlink:href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fc/Foro_Romano.jpg/1200px-Foro_Romano.jpg"  >
 </image>  
 <text id="txt1" x="10" y="240px"  style="fill:none;stroke-width:12;stroke:white;text-transform: uppercase; ">details</text> 
 <text id="txt2" x="10" y="235px"  style="fill:none;stroke-width:5;stroke:white;text-transform: uppercase; ">details</text>
 
 </svg>
 </div>
</html>
```

**Чёрно белый фон:**

```css
#txt1 {
   font: 900 500% 'Arial Black', sans-serif;
  font-size:160px;
   filter:url(#gauss);
} 
#txt2 {
   font: 900 500% 'Arial Black', sans-serif;
  font-size:160px;
}
```

```html
 <div  class="container">
<svg   width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 800 800" >

    <defs>
  <mask id="txt1" width="1000px" height="1000px">
   <rect width="100%" height="100%" filter="url(#gauss)"/>
   <text x="-100" y="200px"  style="fill:white;stroke-width:1;stroke:white;text-transform: uppercase;">details</text>
    </mask> 
 <filter id="gauss"
    x="-20%" y="-20%" width="1000" height="1000">
       <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="20"/> 
      <feOffset dx="10" dy="-10" result="offsetblur"/> 
   </filter>
   </defs>
  
 <image x="-200" y="-410" width="1000px" height="1000px"
 xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7KjZ.jpg"  >
 </image>  
 <text id="txt1" x="10" y="240px"  style="fill:none;stroke-width:12;stroke:white;text-transform: uppercase; ">details</text> 
 <text id="txt2" x="10" y="250px"  style="fill:none;stroke-width:5;stroke:white;text-transform: uppercase; ">details</text>
 
 </svg>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 4):

В общем если требуется создать прозрачность тексту то нам на помощь приходит **SVG** а конкретно **mask** т.е по другому сказать мы маскируем под буквами прозрачность (как меня здесь научили).

```css
html {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-rendering: optimizelegibility;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 900;
}

.text {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  z-index: 10;
}

svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: inherit;
}

svg text {
  text-anchor: middle;
}

svg #alpha {
  fill: #666666;
}

svg #title {
  letter-spacing: -2px;
  font-size: 6em;
  font-weight: 800;
}

svg #subtitle {
  letter-spacing: 8px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

svg #base {
  fill: black;
  -webkit-mask: url(#mask);
  mask: url(#mask);
}

section.intro {
  background: url(https://million-wallpapers.ru/wallpapers/2/79/10148432354989272479.jpg) no-repeat top center;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">
  <svg>
   <defs>
     <mask id="mask" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" >
       <rect id="alpha" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%"/>
       <text id="title" x="50%" y="0" dy="1.58em" font-weight="900">SVG + CSS</text>
       <text id="subtitle" x="50%" y="0" dy="9.8em" font-weight="900">Use it please!</text>
     </mask>
    </defs>

    <rect id="base" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%"/>
  </svg>
</div>

<section class="intro"></section>
```

Пример взят : [отсюда](https://codepen.io/fixcl/pen/CHgrn)

или градиент с маской :

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:300,700");
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Oswald", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
}

svg {
  display: block;
}

picture img {
  position: fixed;
  will-change: transform;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<picture>
  <img src="https://s.cdpn.io/387787/header.jpg" alt="">
  <svg width="100%" height="1280">
    <defs>
      <linearGradient id="gradient" gradientTransform="rotate(75)">
        <stop offset="15%" stop-color="#1a237e" />
        <stop offset="80%" stop-color="#00e5ff" />
      </linearGradient>
      <mask id="mask">
        <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#fff" />
        <text x="10%" y="25%" font-size="4em" font-weight="300">Introducing</text>
        <text x="10%" y="50%" font-size="17em" letter-spacing="10">SVG MASK</text>
      </mask>
    </defs>
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#gradient)" fill-opacity="0.8" mask="url(#mask)" />
  </svg>
</picture>
```

пример взят : [отсюда](https://codepen.io/rynarud/pen/GpYaWv?editors=0110)

Answer (score 2):

Добавьте белый цвет шрифту, добавьте размер тени:

```css
p {
 font-size: 128px;
 font-weight: 700;
 text-shadow: 0 0 100px #131824;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 color: white;
}
```

```html
<p>details</p>
```

Comment: дело в том, что текст должен быть прозрачный. под ним распологается бекграунд

Comment: Тогда без svg вам не обойтись

Comment: @WVFFLIFE это очень важное дополнение, меняющее абсолютно всё - допишите его прямо в текст вопроса (кнопка править)